# Further understanding about namespace in php and laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently learning laravel framework and most of the time it's using namespace, and to further my understanding about namespace I read articles and php documentation about it but none of those discuss or maybe I'm missing the concept as shown below.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class

I don't understand much about `::class`

What is it for?

Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The special `::class` constant are available as of PHP 5.5.0, and allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile, this is useful for namespaced classes:

```
namespace foo {
    class bar {
    }

    echo bar::class; // foo\bar
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php